# Are there any benefits to using settings.json instead of a mongodb collection?

Tags: meteor

Are there any benefits to using settings.json instead of just storing this information in mongodb?

I would have thought that if you store it in a collection, then you can secure it by not publishing the collection in the first place. But you could also then build an admin page where you could update these details in your app, and it would be available straight away with no code reload.

In the meteor Chef's article on building a SaaS using Meteor (https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-a-saas-with-meteor-stripe-part-1/), Ryan Glover espouses the use of settings.json to store your Stripe keys.

Later on he uses it again, but this time to hold the details about the stripe plans. Wouldn't it be better to store this in a collection on mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly, the settings.json file is meant to be used for non changing data like API keys and config info.

Considering that this data doesn't need to be manipulated, it is better to just use a settings.json file rather than a collection. If your going to use a collection than you have to go through the extra steps of pub sub.

Comment: OK, so I guess then it's a convenience factor for static data, with some added security

Answer (score 0):

With settings.json you have an opportunity to use different configuration for different environments (DEV, PROD etc.). Of course you can keep config information in MongoDB but then you need to save also environment information and have to pub/sub based on this.
Why would you do this, while you already have a mechanism for app configuration? In addition, you can set METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for adding to this Areca - I'll give this to Chackerian simply as he answered first with something similar